# How to add rows to jquery table from mysql query with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I need insert rows into a jQuery DataTable from AJAX. In AJAX I call a PHP file when I make a query to my mySql database, but I get show only a character in rows. It is because the format returned is incorrect, but I can't to parse the correct format.

```
$query = "..myquery..";
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    do {
        $arr []= $row['name'];
    } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql));
    echo json_encode($arr); // Here I tried return array without json_encode and a lot of things...
}
```

I know that the format to add the rows with `.DataTable().row.add()` is the below, but I do not get the desired format.

```
[["Element software"], ["Software dist"],["Global envir"], ["Software"], ["Software list"]]
```

How can I get this format in the echo to returned this??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is array of arrays, so you need to push an array to `$arr`, not a string:

```
$query = "..myquery..";
$arr = []; // init an empty array
// no need to do if() and do{}while() inside. You can just while(){} it
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $arr[]= [$row['name']]; // <== these square brackets do the trick  
}
echo json_encode($arr); // still need to json_encode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
    $arr[]= array($row['name']);
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Note the

```
$arr[]= array($row['name']);
```

instead of

```
$arr []= $row['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

One:two run mysql_fetch_array($sql) because php return null;

Two:code ajax for insert table .

```
 $.ajax({
                dataType:"json",
                url:"recive.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:{id:id},
                success: function(res){
                     for(var j=0;j<res.length;j++)
                        {
                             $("#tabel").append("<table ><tr><td style='width:100%;' > "+res[j].id+"</td></tr></table>");
                        }    
                }
```